# The solution set for a diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory

Apart from the solution $t=v=x=1, a=d, b=e, c=f$, is there a way to tell how many solutions the following diophantine equation has?

$$vx(bv-ex)+tx(dx-at)+tv(ft-cv)=0$$

Comment: Assuming all characters occurred in the equation are variables need to be solved, there are infinite solutions as you can see by scaling.

Answer (score 1):

Above equation shown below:

$vx(bv-ex)+tx(dx-at)+tv(ft-cv)=0$  ----(1)

Above has parametric solution:

$a=6(7k-4)$

$b=6(k-2)$

$c=4k(2-k)$

$d=3(7k-4)$

$e=11k-12$

$f=12k(2-k)$

$v=12k(2-k)$

$t=4k(2-k)$

$x=4k(7-k)$

For k=9 we get:

$(a,b,c,d,e,f,v,t,x)=(354,42,-252,177,87,-756,-756,-252,-72)$

Since "k' can take many values's there are infinite solution's to equation (1)

Comment: Am I right that there is no solution set where all the terms are positive?

Answer (score 1):

"OP" requested positive integer solution to below equation:

$vx(bv−ex)+tx(dx−at)+tv(ft−cv)=0$

$a=5(5k-12)$

$b=(5k-12)$

$c=2(k-2)$

$d=(9k-20)$

$e=(3k-8)$

$f=6(k-2)$

$v=3(k-4)$

$t=(k-4)$

$x=(k-4)(12-5k)$

for, $k=0$ & after making a sign change &

removing common factor's we get:

$(a,b,c,d,e,f)=(15,3,1,5,2,3)$ &

$(v,t,x)=(3,1,12)$